# Automatically name array elements from database column name in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, encode

I want to create an array to then encode by JSON, right now I manually name array elements based on column names, if its a small number of columns is OK, but if it would be 1000 columns. Is there a way to automatically name the array elements?

Right now:

```
$resulta = mysql_query("SELECT bla,bla1bla2 from ..."); 
$toEncodeArray = array();
if($resulta) 
{
 while($columna = mysql_fetch_array($resulta)) 
 {
  $toEncodeArray[] = array(
   "bla" => $columna['bla'], 
   "bla1" => $columna['bla1'],
    ...
  );
 }
}
```

Would like somthing like:

```
while($columna = mysql_fetch_array($resulta)) 
{
 $toEncodeArray[] = array(<same name as column> => $columna[<iterate columns?]);
}
```

Using only $columna = mysql_fetch_array($resulta) and then encode $columna gives me garbage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: If you have a DB table with a thousand columns you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @vascowhite Where do I get a source that tells me that a given table X should only be up to N-columns? It will be very interesting to find a fixed number like, you only should have "24" columns, or "99" or "43", I mean "where" it begins to be too much becomes an extremely subjetive situation that depends on the problem itself. As I clearly stated, it was an assumption of 1000.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

```
$res = mysql_query(...);
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) )
{
    print_r($row);
    // or echo $row['something'];
}
```